# Gettting First Element Added to a Queue as Null

Tags: java, c++, queue

hey guys this is my code:

```
public void add(int data) {
Node n = new Node(data);         
    if (n.next == null) {
        head = tail = n; 
    } 
    else {
        tail.next = n;
        n.next = null;
        n = tail;
    }
}
```

when i add one element to a new Queue, and run, i list what the head, tail, and list are:

```
Output:
Head=null Tail=null {};
```

{} signifies the list is empty when it shouldn't be, what am i doing wrong...

Comment: You should tag this C or C++ (whichever you're using) so this gets some more views.

Comment: I'm new to the site in terms of posting, thanks, how do i update the tag field

Comment: You're welcome, you should just be able to click "edit" just under your post, above these comments :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your logic for inserting in a queue is wrong ...

Please look at the algorithm and implementation of queue [here](http://www.programming-techniques.com/2011/11/stack-and-queue-implementation-of.html)

For your example, try updating this:

```
public void add(int data) {
    Node n = new Node(data); 
    n.next = null;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = n;
    } else {
        tail->next = n;
    }

    tail = n;
}
```

Comment: in the first if

it should have been: 
if(head == null)

thanks Rakhi